# Javascript code problems with " and '

Tags: javascript

Normally we can use `var a = "<a href='index.php'>index</a>";` but I need to have more then 2 `'` in the same line of code as it follows:

```
var status = "<a href='javascript:window.open('atendimento.php','hhchat','top=70,left=70,width=480,height=450,status=no,location=no,statusbar=no');void(0);'><img src='img/atendimento.png' width='160' border='0' /></a>";
```

So the problem is that it starts and finishes the line code here: `'javascript:window.open('`

And I need it to continue till the end of the line .. How can it be done?

Comment: I would avoid trying to generate HTML as strings.  If this is in-browser code, use the DOM functions to create HTML elements (`var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href="javascript:...";`).  On the server side, use a template system that handles the quoting for you.

Comment: There are cheap template systems that work fine client-side too - my personal favorite is [doT](http://olado.github.io/doT/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `"` and escape it:

```
var status = "<a href='javascript:window.open(\"atendimento.php\",\"hhchat\", ...
```

Although this is a perfect example why you should use unobtrusive JavaScript to bind events - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript and you won't have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your characters:

```
var status = "<a href=\"javascript:window.open('atendimento.php','hhchat','top= ...
```

More info at W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp

Comment: Ideology aside, I find that certain parts of the website explain the basics of Javascript very well. For example, this is the MDN page which explains escaping in Javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals
That's a little verbose for someone just learning Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash to escape a quote inside a string:

```
"<a href='javascript:window.open(\"atendimento.php\" ....
```

Or better yet, consider best practice, which is to avoid having your JS code inline in your HTML.

Instead, you should be considering defining a `click` event defined for your element in separate JS code. This would remove the whole issue of the nested quotes.

Comment: Wouldn't a click event not work in the case of a click to open in a new tab (ctr+click for example)?

Answer (score 0):

use escape characters as below after href=

```
var status = "<a href=\"javascript:window.open('atendimento.php','hhchat','top=70,left=70,width=480,height=450,status=no,location=no,statusbar=no');void(0);\"><img  src='img/atendimento.png' width='160' border='0' /></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Interchange " and ' and then escape \"

```
var status = "<a href='javascript:window.open(\"atendimento.php\"...
```